# Product Page - Split Screen Scrolling

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

http://looker-theme.myshopify.com/collections/furniture/products/uchiva
 
I really like the scroll effect in the link above and want to incorporate this into my site which uses the 'Debut' theme.
The goal would be to have the left side of the product page scroll while the right side stays fixed.
Has anyone done something similar using the Debut theme before?
 
If so, how did you go about this?
 
Thanks!

Position: fixed

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some code for you

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="scroll">
        <img src="">//Put some image inside src</img>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
        <img src="">//Something too</img>
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
    .content{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .fixed{
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }

    .fixed img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .scroll{
        width: 50%;
    }

    .scroll img{
        width: 100%;
    }
```

In this case I used images, but you can put whatever you want inside the div.

if you want to make it more responsive and interesting you should add some javascript, so you can control when the container stops being fixed, you could achieve that by doing:

```
window.onscroll = function (){
 var element = document.getElementById('YOUR ELEMENT ID'); // The fixed element in this case

  if(window.pageYOffset > 1000 ){ // YOU DECIDE WHEN. window.pageYOffset says to you where the scroll is in pixels looking at the Y axis
    element.classList.add('CLASS'); //Create a class that eliminates the position fixed with something like position: unset
  } else {
    element.classList.remove('CLASS'); //REMOVING THE CLASS SO IT WILL BE FIXED AGAIN
  }
}
```

You could start with that.